# Do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”?

Tags: r, shiny

Why do I get an error on RStudio for this line below:

```
# Calculate the end day of current month.
# example: 2016-07-31
endDayOfCurrentMonth <- as.Date(format(as.Date(format(as.Date(Sys.Date(),"%Y%m%d"), "%Y%m01"),"%Y%m%d") +31,"%Y%m01"), "%Y%m%d") -1
```

Error:

> do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”

In my RStudio console:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5097
Warning in data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning: Error in as.Date.default: do not know how to convert 'date' to class “Date”
Stack trace (innermost first):
    105: as.Date.default
    104: as.Date
    103: filter
    102: _f [source/function/getStreamDf.R#46]
    101: withVisible
    100: rr
     99: renderPlot [/var/srv/shiny-server/dustboxes/dustbox1/server.R#91]
     89: <reactive:plotObj>
     78: plotObj
     77: origRenderFunc
     76: output$plot
      1: runApp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this.

Comment: I am getting `"2017-03-31"`

Comment: you can use `ceiling_date()` from `lubridate` `ceiling_date(today(),unit="month")-1`

Comment: thanks guys. i think the error it is not caused by `endDayOfCurrentMonth <- as.Date(format(as.Date(format(as.Date(Sys.Date(),"%Y%m%d"), "%Y%m01"),"%Y%m%d") +31,"%Y%m01"), "%Y%m%d") -1`. but something else! I dunno what is causing it!